# Laravel 9 $currentPageUrl without pagination

Tags: laravel

Current case

I Have that

```
<meta name="canonical" href="{!! $currentPageUrl !!}">
```

Get : [www.domain.com/search?q=green+word&page=2](http://www.domain.com/search?q=green+word&page=2)

I want

[www.domain.com/search?q=green+word](http://www.domain.com/search?q=green+word)

Comment: You need to show the code of how you are setting `$currentPageUrl`

Comment: where i can find it please ?

Comment: @Med where does `$currentPageUrl` come from? it had to be set in the view or passed to the view at some point

Answer (score 2, accepted):

can use this

```php
request()->fullUrlWithoutQuery('page');
```

Comment: This will show the url without query parameters, the OP wants the q parameter in the url.

Comment: url: http://127.0.0.1:8008/admin?q=data&page=1  result: http://127.0.0.1:8008/admin?q=data auto append query string without pagination @GertB.

Comment: ow, my bad. I was half asleep, I think